# WordPress AJAX via jQuery load vs going through admin-ajax.php

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

To me it seems like the current best practice for implementing AJAX in WordPress is sending AJAX calls through admin-ajax.php (as described here for example: [Smashing magazine article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/))

It seems so much simpler to me to just use jQuery's load function and just grab the content from a link that way. Are there any disadvantages to this approach versus the other one?

Also, would it be safe to use jQuery load for a Woocommerce cart or checkout page - eg. instead of having the page reload to view the cart, or to go to checkout from the cart, is it safe to grab them with the load function instead? I tested it and it seems to work, but I'm concerned that it may have some sort of security issues I don't know about - it just seems too easy and that makes me suspicious :)